# c++ unable to open raw socket using Ubuntu and Netbeans 6.9

Tags: c++, ubuntu, netbeans, raw-ethernet

I'm trying to send/recv raw ethernet under Ubuntu.

I've no problem running code in c through the terminal.

However when i've tried to convert the code to c++ using 
Netbeans IDE 6.9 it fails to open the raw socket.
calling:

```
socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))) == -1)
```

always return -1. error : "operation not permitted"

Comment: Does it work if you run your application through terminal as root?

Comment: I figured out that running the code through the terminal using "sudo"
solves the problem.
Googling around I understand that there is a possibility to configure the Netbeans to do the same. I still did not manage to do so..

Answer (score 0):

You always need *root* permissions to send / receive something through *raw sockets*.

Here's how to configure NetBeans to run your application as root:

1. **`Right click on project -> Properties -> Run`**
2. Set **`Run Command`** to **`sudo "${OUTPUT_PATH}"`** (default is `"${OUTPUT_PATH}"`)